# Cron Job Scheduled did not run on specified time

Tags: php, cron, crontrigger

I scheduled a cron job to hit a page 1st of every month at 12.00AM but the cron didn't work for some reason.
The below is the cron I have used :

```
0 0 1 * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronleave.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using sample :

```
0 0 1 * * wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cronleave.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and check time server

Comment: wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null  is this required to use in cron ?

Comment: Yes @VinitSinkar . you just change url .

Comment: 59 0 1 * *  wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cronleave.php >/dev/null 2>&1 i tried with this cron but still it didn't work.

Comment: 59 0 1 * * => once a month , in time 00:59 . and A month later is executed

Comment: i would like to run the cron from today at 3:30 pm once every month of 1st.Please suggest the appropriate practice to make this cron run.

Comment: `30 15 * 1 *  wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cronleave.php >/dev/null 2>&1` you just change url in cron .

Comment: i tried with your code to test 25 13 1 * * wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://domain.com/cronleave.php >/dev/null 2>&1 still it didn't work.Any help for this.